# Assign range to Data Validation - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I m trying to pass in a data validation a range but i m receiving an error. Any ideas?

Error in line:

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=rng
```

**Error:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = wsIndex.Range("A1:A5")

        With wsIndex.Range("K1").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=rng
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error message? And what is the value in `wsIndex.Range("A1:A5")`?

Comment: see edited answer.

Comment: Try changing `Formula1:=rng` for `Formula1:=rng.Address`

Comment: @Damian this does not work.

Comment: Sorry, change `Formula1:=rng` for `Formula1:= "=" & rng.Address`

Comment: @Damian this is working!! post is as a solution!\

Comment: For others who may see this. This error is typical when an operation is performed that is not "legal" under the current application. In Excel this usually means writing an illegal formula or pasting text that starts with an equal (=)  sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst you can reference a range (as per @Damian) you could also work with arrays:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim lst As Variant
lst = Application.Transpose(wsIndex.Range("A1:A5"))
With wsIndex.Range("K1").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=Join(lst, ",")
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: How to declare `lst`?

Comment: thanks for the answer, i will prefer this answer because it fulfill my needs coz the range with the data is in a different sheet from the validation

Comment: @Error1004, glad it helped you out!

Comment: How to display the first item from the list in K1?

Comment: @Error1004, try: `wsIndex.Range("K1") = lst(1)`

Answer (score 2):

DataValidation won't accept `Range` only a `String` so you can do this:

`Formula1:= "=" & rng.Address` because is expecting a formula.

Comment: Yes, + :). It doesn't have to be a formula though (can just be a string of values)